# Word ordering for "so" as conjunction

Tags: word-order, conjunction

> Today is warm, so we will go outside.

Which of the following word order is correct?

> (a) Heute ist es warm, so gehen wir raus.
>
> (b) Heute ist es warm, so wir gehen raus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out, "also" is the correct word to use here. In this case, since "also" is a conjunctional adverb (I don't actually know, whether it would be called this way in English, the correct German term is "Konjunktionaladverb"), the correct word order is "also - verb - subject". This applies also to all other words of similar type like "dennoch", "doch", "ebenso" or "insofern" (and many more).

But let me add some other uses of "so" that were not mentioned already. You can use the German "so" in the sense of the English "if" - in very formal circumstances:

> So Gott will, wird es gut gehen.

If God wants, it'll be alright.

Another usage that you might frequently encounter is in the sense of "like" as a filling word in colloquial language:

> Er sagte so: "Hau ab" und ich so: "Nein"

He said "Get lost" and I answered "No" (feel free to add "like": He said like, "Get lost"...)

Comment: An idiomatic translation of *Er sagte so: Hau ab* and *und ich so: Nein* would be *And he's like: f___ off!* and *And I'm like: No!*.

Answer (score 1):

In German I don't believe you can use *so* as a conjunction, but rather *also,* which fills the 1st position in the sentence or clause sending the subject to the 3rd position.

> Heute ist es warm, also gehen wir aus.

contrasted with

> Heute ist es warm, und wir gehen aus.

Comment: Verb is still in 2nd position, as clause+`also` only fill up one position together.

Answer (score 0):

You only use so when you comparing people or things:

Ich bin so alt wie du

I am as old as you (are)

> `Du bist größer als er`

You are taller than he (is)

It can also mean`such` or `like that`:

> `Schau mich nicht so an`!

Dont look at me like that!

> `So ist das Leben`.

That's the life.

In this context, so is not used here but also instead:

Heute ist es warm,`also` gehen wir aus.